# Problems with syncing emails on Galaxy SIII

Tags: sync, email

I recently did a software update to 4.3 and now my email account loads emails in as unread and I go in to mark them as read but within 5 minutes they change to unread and I get new noticiations.  Can someone please tell me how to fix this problem.

Answer (score 0):

I think software update has reverted all your settings, follow the steps :

1. If you are using gmail app ,  then you should go to settings and check the concerned setting and also go to phone settings and under Accounts click Google and sync now.
2. If you are using stock email app follow the above procedure but im accounts select email and sync. Also check the email app settings.

Reply if problems persist.

Comment: Thanks, have made sure that the Sync settings show sync now but this has not sorted the problem.  I still get emails coming up as not read all the time.